# Efficiently Reading A CSV File With 5.6 Million Rows C#

Tags: c#, csv, sql-server-2016, sqlbulkcopy

I've written a C# console application to automatically go out and download a 639 MB zip file. Then, the zip file is extracted. The csv file that I need to read is now 6.5 GB in size. It has about 5.6 million rows and 329 columns of which I need 36 of those 329 columns.
My objective is be able to read that csv file and insert records into a Microsoft SQL 2016 database and update database records where the NPI number is found.
I'm wondering what would be an efficient way of performing these operations? I was looking at a few different ways to insert the records and one heavily suggested way is to utilize the `SqlBulkCopy`. I appreciate the assistance and hopefully I formatted things correctly.

Comment: You can do it in chunks and use `SqlBulkCopy`. I am not sure why you want this to be efficient: It is not like you need to do this every minute or so, it is just a one time process or a process that needs to be done every now and then. Keep in mind `SqlBulkCopy` does not support updates, only inserts. To do updates, insert to a staging table and once that is all done, execute a stored procedure wherein you will do  the update or insert. Finally delete data from your staging table.

Comment: How often are you doing this?  Every day, every week, every month?

Comment: @CodingYoshi, The efficiency part is mainly a personal choice. Plus I really don't want to eat up system resources without the need.

Comment: @cup, I will be running this weekly at midnight on Sunday's.